# Two outputstreams?

Tags: java, sockets, io, stream

I have the following code where I'm trying to create two different types of outputstreams. This doesn't seem to work. What would be the correct way to create two outputstreams? Specifically, one dataoutputstream and one objectoutputstream?

```
connect();

try (DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)) {

        outputStream.writeUTF("saveFile");
        outputStream.writeUTF(serverName);
        File fileToSave = new File(localName);
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fileToSave.toPath());

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(fileContent);

        return true;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    return false;
} finally {
    disconnect();
}
```

After doing some debugging it seems just like the outputstream isn't working. If I only have one of the two, the two "writeUTF" statements will execute.

If I keep both of the outputstreams, the message never reaches the server.

Comment: Please define "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: Sorry, updated main post

Comment: is there any reason you're not using one try statement like this:   try (DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)) {

Comment: @dienerd Tried that too, no luck.

Comment: @Lithicas sorry i wasn't more clear. i didn't think that would fix your problem. i was only trying to help you write better code. there's no need for that embedded try within the other try :-)

Comment: @dienerd Actually it gave me the same problem I have now. It like just stops execution. Is it even possible to have two outputstreams on the same socket?

Comment: i recommend adding some logging statements in there to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: Also, write out you Exception stacktrace.

Comment: After doing some debugging it seems just like the outputstream isn't working. If I only have one of the two, the two "writeUTF" statements will execute.

If I keep both of the outputstreams, the message never reaches the server.

Comment: this is the answer you're looking for. the two streams are not knowing what the other is doing:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170275/creating-2-streams-with-one-socket] (Creating 2 streams with one socket)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to move the two "writeUTF" statements above the second try block.

```
connect();

try (DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
    outputStream.writeUTF("saveFile");
    outputStream.writeUTF(serverName);

    try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)) {

        File fileToSave = new File(localName);
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fileToSave.toPath());

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(fileContent);

        return true;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    return false;
} finally {
    disconnect();
}
```

Now the code executes properly.

Comment: The solution is to make your sending code exactly symmetrical with your receiving code, which it clearly wasn't. Or lose the `DataInput/OuputStream`s altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `new ObjectOutputStream(...)` writes a header to the stream, and evidently your reading code isn't symmetrical with this code, i.e. it does the `readUTF()` steps before constructing the `ObjectInputStream`, so the header isn't consumed yet, so the `readUTF()` steps see it, and barf.

The solution is that you don't need to do this at all. The `DataOutputStream` is completely pointless here. `ObjectOutputStream` has all the methods of `DatataOutputStream`, and more, and similarly for the input streams.

In general this kind of thing is not possible when one or more of the streams is buffered, as `ObjectInputStream` is.